# How is the "AppData\Local\Application Data\" directory linked?

Tags: windows-7, windows, junction, mklink

I deleted "AppData\Local\Application Data\" from my profile and I want to create the link again.  My problem is that if I create an mklink to %localappdata%, it behaves differently than the original:

```
mklink /D "Application Data" %localappdata%
```

It creates a directory with a never ending infinite loop of "Application Data" \ "Application Data" \ ... folders.

But the original is not like this in Windows, it is a different link.  How is it done and how can I recreate the original link structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd. Did you try typing out the path?

I personally wouldn't bother with it.  It's there for App compatability reasons. Good behaving apps will use the correct shell alias, not the hardcoded BS.

Comment: MKLINK has 3 options: /D symbolic link, /H hard link, /J junction. Maybe it's one of H or J. Do you know how could I check on a reference folder what kind of linking is it?

Comment: `Dir /a /p` .  `/a` just lists attributes, including link type.